# What is the name of this technique?

Tags: html, css

Here is the link: http://codepen.io/uniZero/pen/fvkjJ

I tried to Google "fixed image backgrounds" or something similar but the result is not the same beautiful webpage with multiple backgrounds that are changing when users are scrolling the site.

I'd appreciate if someone can point me into the right direction so I can explore more and learn how to make something similar?

What are the pro and cons for such type of websites???

Thank you all in advance :)

Comment: It's a CSS3 selector.  I don't think it's called anything.  The background-size is set to cover; attachment to fixed; and position to center center.  The combination of those 3 things, with CSS3, gives you that effect.

Comment: It's a style used a lot on 'single page websites'

Comment: Alright, this helps a bit. Thanks people!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the backgrounds are not "fixed". What's fixed is the `<header>`.

This technique is called as... ta-da! Fixed headers. Or, when you are using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com), they call this "Fixed Navbar" - and it's a very common component in websites using it.

The key of these is just setting an `position: fixed` (as you may have noticed), and a possible `z-index` value, so it's always on top.

Comment: Hi! Yes, the header is fixed I understand that part but I was wondering how to make a single page website with a multiple photobackgrounds that are changing when users scroll down the page??? I think it is very efficient as a user experience. Sorry for a basic question, I am still new to web development. Thanks for your patience!